# Xor sum of array

Tags: algorithm

There are N different colors.Every color has a different intensity value N[i](1 ≤ i ≤ N).
Alice wants to mix all the colors available to her and make a new color out of the colors available.

The Mixing is defined as a process in which she takes XOR of each color with every other colors available to her and then add them all to get the intensity of the resulting color.

Example : let N=2 and colors be [4,5] then here answer is 1.

Please explain how to approach this question if

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 10^6
1 ≤ N[i] ≤ 2^32
```

Clearly I can't go for each possible way.

Comment: So she does `sum{N[i] xor N[j], i > j}`? How did you get the 14?

Comment: Could you please add a more formalized description of what the answer is. I do not understand what we need to compute.

Comment: @IVlad Sorry it was 1 and not 14

Comment: @kraskevich See IVIad comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let's solve this problem for each bit independently.
2. For a fixed bit `b`, we can compute the number of such pairs `i` and `j` that `i > j` and the bit `b` is set in `N[i] xor N[j]` using an algorithm expressed in this pseudo code:

   ```
   // The amount of numbers where the bit b is not set.
   count0 = 0
   // The amount of numbers where this bit is set.
   count1 = 0
   // The number of pairs (i, j): i > j and this bit is set in N[i] xor N[j]
   pairsCount = 0
   for i <- 0 ... n - 1:
       if the bit b is set in N[i]:
           // This number gives one when xored with a number in which
           // this bit is not set.
           pairsCount += count0
           count1++
       else
           // This number gives one when xored with a number in which
           // this bit is set.
           pairsCount += count1
           count0++
   return pairsCount
   ```

   When we know the number of such pairs, we should just add `pairsCount * 2 ** b` to the answer.
3. So the solution is: iterate over all bits from `0` to `32` and run the algorithm described in 2. for each of them.

The time complexity is `O(N * log MAX_VALUE)`, which looks good for the given constraints.